# Deeplink in Windows phone app shows alert if app is not installed

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, uwp, deep-linking

We want to implement deeplink in our certian mobile pages and want the user to go to the app if app is installed otherwise continue using mobile site. Issue is on iOS and Android if app is not installed chrome/safari doesn't show any alert but in Windows it shows alert   - > Sear for app in store > We don't want this alert

We are trying following

window.location = 'myapp://in/wv/http://m.google.com';
    
    }

Is there a way to disable this?

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The dialog indicates there is a URI scheme or file that the device isn't sure what to do with. Some details in RE to that would help us help you

Comment: So if you go to any deeplink for any app on android/iOS it silently opens the app or go to mobile site. But in case of Windows we really can't achieve this. I hope you got my point.